# CodeIgniter Form - Dynamic Validation with UIKit

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation, uikit

I'm currently using UIKit framework.

My views:

`<input class="uk-input" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">`

I want to add the class **uk-form-danger** to my input upon validation such as:

`<input class="uk-input uk-form-danger" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">`

In my controller:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    die();
}
else
{
    // i want to dynamically add that uk-form-danger class to corresponding input
}
```

In [CodeIgniter's form validation documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=form%20validation), it says

`<?php echo form_error('field name', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>`

This is correct the way to change the form error delimiter individually, but I don't want to change the whole element, rather add the `extra class` in the `input element` and not nesting it in an extra `div`. 
How do I implement this? Do I need some javascript because I don't want to add extra scripts. 
Otherwise, if it isn't possible, I will resort to use the alert component instead (which will end up creating another element but not highlighting the input (text field) like what I've planned to do.

Comment: You can not 'highlight' from server side just like that. If you want the page to be modified without being reloaded (i.e. not by sending a request to the server), you'll need to do that from the client side - you need JS here.
Else, you will need to send a request to the server and then render the form again

Comment: Thank you for the heads up.. I'm now resorting to use the alert component instead. Not the best UX, especially it will eat up more space on mobile, but I guess it can still do the trick. `<?php echo form_error('first_name', '<div class="uk-alert-danger" uk-alert><a class="uk-alert-close" uk-close></a><p class="uk-text-small">&uarr; ', '</p></div>'); ?>`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? 
Basically, there are 3 options:
1) highlight a 'bad' input after the user moves to another input
2) highlight all the 'bad' inputs after the submit button has been clicked - but not allowing the use to submit it
3) allow user to the submit and if and error occurs -  render the form again with 'highlights'.

Which is the one you desire?

Comment: While, all your suggestions are correct. This user experience is rather a personal preference. Honestly, I didn't think of the #1 and #2 but when I think back it's a lot awesome and cooler if I can do the validation before submitting, however CI's can only validate after submitting the form. Doing this in "client side" requires extra effort on programming and makes my life more complicated. Lol. What I'm doing now is like #3 just processing the validation after submitting the form. I'm not good in javascript (or ajax? whatever the technology is called)...

Comment: This isn't ajax and it's actually quite easier than the solution you're aiming for. Try to look up 'client side form validation'.
This - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp could be start. 
If you need more help, let me know.

Comment: Thank you, I just read the examples. It seems easy to understand. I was trying to use CI's built-in validation. This is the reason why, I'm not sure which "technology" to use. (for example) html even have it's own `required` but i resort to use CI since I'm trying to avoid any other extra dependencies... I was looking to achieve the above solely in CI without writing extra javascript... Thank you, I will read more on js validation...

Comment: Hi @Roysh. After 2 days of researching, I ended up using [SweetAlert.js](https://sweetalert.js.org/) - I think it's pretty cool. I'm combining it with codeigniter's session flashdata and show the notification animation through javascript on window load. I think this is better in terms of user experience even though I didn't implement it using AJAX, it requires page redirection. However, everything works well, I'm able to show some basic information such as "login/registration successful/error"... Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: Sure thing man!

Comment: Feel free to reach out when you need